# Set object properties depending on Size Class in iOS8

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

I am new to iOS development, I have read about size classes, I have a question about setting properties (or just calling methods with some parameter) depending on ViewController's size class. I am developing a simple radio app, for app design I decided to use Collection View in which I want display logo image. Because I develop universal app and I want to place images in 3 columns or rows on both iPhone snd iPad versions, I need 4 Collection Views for iPhone and iPad for portrait and landscape orientations. For example for iPhone's Collection View I set 75x75 image size for cell, for iPad's 200x200. So for one object (radio station) I need to create 2 image sets, because I do not want just to use the biggest iPad's images on iPhone for two reasons: higher CPU usage, scale issues.

So question is which is the best solution to create objects in array for Collection View with appropriate image size depending on Size Class? Is it good solution to use UITraitCollection to determine Size Class in the viewDidLoad method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You question indicates you need first to take time to learn some stuff on iOS.

*Like you I had to start and learn : it is no problem.*

### have a closer to `auto layout`in iOS

- [www.raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial)

### then see how easy and fun is iOS development (just need to practice to understand how easy it is). Here is a `tutorial for collection views`:

- [www.raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1)

### image scaled

- in your image asset

  - place image with name terminated with
  - nothing, @2x, 3x
    -> easy way to scale image : I use sketch.

Comment: In the first tutorial they use one image view with one size, in the second tutorial they get images from flickr in the iPad app. Did not find answer. For size classes we can show/hide view, enable/disable constraints, change constants of constraints, change fonts, but can't change attributes of views, so I decided to use different collection views with different settings for different devices and orientations. But the main question is how to deal with images.

Comment: I have found article about setting images for different size classeshttps://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingImageSets.html